# Regex named grouping

Tags: regex, language-agnostic

Can you have dynamic naming in regex groups? Something like

```
reg = re.compile(r"(?PText|Or|Something).*(?PTextIWant)")

r = reg.find("TextintermingledwithTextIWant")

r.groupdict()["Text"] == "TextIWant"
```

So that depending on what the beggining was, group["Text"] == TextIWant

Updated to make the quesetion more clear.

Comment: *looks at clock* Yup, it was about time for a terrible idea to come around...

Comment: Terrible ideas are good ideas sometimes =D

Comment: could you elaborate why you are trying to do this and what the desired end result is?

Comment: Well mostly because I like needlessly complicated regexes. But I was just curous mainly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some regex engines support this, some don't.  [This site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) says that Perl, Python, PCRE (and thus PHP), and .NET support it, all with slightly different syntax:

```
+--------+----------------------------+----------------------+------------------+
| Engine |           Syntax           |    Backreference     |     Variable     |
+--------+----------------------------+----------------------+------------------+
| Perl   | (?<name>...), (?'name'...) | \k<name>, \k'name'   | %+{name}         |
|        | (?P<name>...)              | \g{name}, (?&name)*  |                  |
|        |                            | (?P>name)*           |                  |
+--------+----------------------------+----------------------+------------------+
| Python | (?P<name>...)              | (?P=name), \g<name>  | m.group('name')  |
+--------+----------------------------+----------------------+------------------+
| .NET   | (?<name>...), (?'name'...) | \k<name>, \k'name'   | m.Groups['name'] |
+--------+----------------------------+----------------------+------------------+
| PCRE   | (?<name>...), (?'name'...) | \k<name>, \k'name'   | Depends on host  |
|        | (?P<name>...)              | \g{name}, \g<name>*  | language.        |
|        |                            | \g'name'*, (?&name)* |                  |
|        |                            | (?P>name)*           |                  |
+--------+----------------------------+----------------------+------------------+
```

This is **not** a complete list, but it's what I could find.  If you know more flavors, add them!  The backreference forms with a `*` are those which are "recursive" as opposed to just a back-reference; I believe this means they match the *pattern* again, not what was *matched* by the pattern.  Also, I arrived at this by reading the docs, but there could well be errors—this includes some languages I've never used and some features I've never used.  Let me know if something's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is worded kind of funny, but I think what you are looking for is a non-capturing group.  Make it like this:

`(?:Must_Match_This_First)What_You_Want(?:Must_Match_This_Last)`

The `?:` is what designates a that a group matches, but does not capture.

Answer (score 0):

You could first build the string in a dynamic way and then pass it to the Regex engine.